# How to handle "promise rejections are deprecated"

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, promise

I'm trying to get my head wrap around with promise and I'm getting this error complaining about unhandled promise rejection but I do have a `catch` if it is reject!

Can anybody please help me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

function searchTextOnGoogle() {
  var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

  driver.get("www.google.com").then(function() {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Automation")).click().then(function() {
      driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(title);
          driver.quit();
        }, 5000);
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Error:

> (node:200092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:200092) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the  future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
>   the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

entire error message:

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:62260/devtools/browser/6dd5b3dc-f6bb-4147-9421-a6e0e172017b(node:191496)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: InvalidArgumentError: invalid
>   argument   (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
>       at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\promise\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:550:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (C:\promise\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:563:13)
>       at Executor.execute (C:\promise\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:489:26)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>       at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (C:\promise\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:699:17)
>   (node:191496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:191496) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Which line throws? Is it the `driver.quit`, or what?

Comment: does not give me specify line number, I updated my question with entire error message which I'm getting.

Comment: You don't have a `.catch()` on `driver.getTitle().then()`.  You don't have a `.catch()` on `driver.get("www.google.com").then()`.  Probably these should all be chained together (by returning the inner promises) and then you have one `.catch()` at the top level.  As it is now, you only have a `.catch()` on the middle level.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what's throwing, if you have `searchTextOnGoogle` return a Promise that's properly chained with all asynchronous operations inside, and then call `.catch` on the call of `searchTextOnGoogle`, all errors should be properly caught. Use an async function to make things more readable, too:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function searchTextOnGoogle() {
  var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

  await driver.get("www.google.com");
  await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Automation")).click();
  const title = await driver.getTitle();
  await delay(5000);
  console.log(title);
  await driver.quit();
}

searchTextOnGoogle()
  .catch(console.log);
```

Note that `.quit` returns a Promise too, and you needed to properly chain the asynchronous operations inside the `setTimeout` with the outer Promise chain.

The error might be resulting from the line:

```
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

The [docs say](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html) that the parameter to `.get` should be the fully qualified URL, so a solution may be to change it to:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

or something of the sort.

Comment: Did you try passing a fully qualified URL to `.get`?

Answer (score -1):

Problem with your code is that it’s not chained properly. The way you are calling different functions, you’ll have to have catch after every then! Instead you can create a chain of promises as @CertainPerformance recommended. You can then use just one `.catch` at the end of chain. Reference below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining